# How to pass raw text from Flask to HTML in the most correct way?

Tags: html, flask

I have a flask app for time series forecasting, I want to show in the HTLM 
[the result of dataframe.describe()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc7y9.png):

But, when I pass the content to the html view [I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWNaO.png) (the underlined text):

How can I "format" the output of the function, for showing in the most appropiate way?

I'm passing to the template from flask:

```
    return render_template(content = df.describe())
```

In the Html I have:

```
{{ content }}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution could be parse your dataframe as html table

```
>> import pandas as pd
>> import numpy as np
>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2), list('AB'), list('XY'))
>> print(df.to_html()) # <- here

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>X</th>
      <th>Y</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>B</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

you can also pass the dateframe to context and iterate with for loop